Spring Boot Endpoint Returns 404 Only on Production Server, Works Fine on Localhost
I'm running a Spring Boot application with Spring Security on my production server, and I encounter a 404 Not Found error when accessing certain endpoints that work perfectly on my local environment.
Problem:
When I make a request to https://api.example.com/user-profile/auth-data from my frontend (and even from Postman), I receive the following response:
{
    "timestamp": "2024-10-29T15:56:39.325+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/user-profile/auth-data"
}

However, on my local machine, the same code and endpoint work without issues. I’m using JWT for authentication, and I’ve already configured CORS and CSRF in my Spring Security setup.
Configuration Details:
Here’s my SecurityConfiguration class:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@AllArgsConstructor
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.dynamicquotation.dq"})
public class SecurityConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    private final JwtFilter jwtFilter;
    private final DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(request -> {
                    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
                    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("https://example.com", "https://accounts.google.com"));
                    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
                    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
                    configuration.setExposedHeaders(List.of("Authorization"));
                    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
                    return configuration;
                }))
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);

        http.sessionManagement(sess -> sess.sessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy()));

        // Authorization
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                auth
                        .requestMatchers("/auth/login", "/auth/is-token-valid", "/logout", "/contact", "/quotation/single-quotation/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        );

        http.oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults());
        http.httpBasic(withDefaults());

        // logout
        http.logout(l -> l
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) -> response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK))
                .addLogoutHandler((request, response, authentication) -> {
                    // Additional logout handler
                }).permitAll());

        http.addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
...

Nginx Configuration:
I'm also using Nginx as a reverse proxy with the following configuration:
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name api.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.com/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

Network Tab Screenshot:
In the following screenshot from the browser’s Network tab, you see the 404 errors on specific endpoints (auth-data, pending-quotations, etc.) while others like is-token-valid work fine.

is-token-valid is permitted, but other endpoints, such as auth-data are not permitted, as the user should be authenticated first. In browser, I am signed in via OAuth (Google) and receive the cookies token and JSESSIONID.
Question:
What could be causing the 404 error only on the production server, despite the endpoint working locally? Could there be any configuration or environment issue I’m overlooking?
Update
See the difference between the controllers:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthController {
    @GetMapping("/is-token-valid")
    public ResponseEntity<Response> isTokenValid(@RequestParam("token") String token) { // Status 200

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user-profile")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserProfileController {
    @GetMapping("/auth-data")
    public ResponseEntity<Response> getAuthData(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String authorizationHeader) { // Status 404

@RequestMapping("/quotation")
@RestController
public class QuotationController {
    @GetMapping(value = "/list")
    public List<AllQuotationsResponse> listQuotations(@ModelAttribute("token") String token) { // Status 404

I figured out that it's because of @RequestHeader('Authorisation') and @ModelAttribute('token'). Because if I remove the parameters, the controllers are invoked. But how do I fix this?

As a wild guess, I would take a look at the TLS certificates as a starting point. Are you using the ones for the corresponding hosts on your local and production environment? Are you by any chance using self signed ones locally and let's encrypt on production?

@KDW in my local environment, I'm not using any SSL certificates (it's just running on http). On the production server, I use Let's Encrypt for SSL. Additionally, the frontend and API are hosted on different servers in production, each with its own SSL certificate.

I have a hard time believing this works locally, since oauth2login does not return any tokens to the frontend. it logs you in with whatever defined provider and then returns a session cookie to the frontend, never exposing any JWTs to the frontend, as handing out a JWT to a frontend is dangerous and should of course never be done. There is too much information missing here to provide any answer, as in debug logs, configuration, what the full requests look like and full classes with annotations etc.

@Toerktumlare thank you, your comment was very helpful! It highlights that my approach was totaly wrong, as I was sending the token to the frontend and frontend created a cookie then, which was not secure of course. I guess, I should create a cookie from the backend side, which should be HttpOnly and Secure. Both of them are missing in my current cookie.

Read this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2

I can't see what may occur directly. But, I suggest you can try with logging. Config the server log with nginx and with the Spring Boot rquests. Go debug with the error log. You will able to find what may occur the error.
